# Putnam 1990 A1 Induction Help

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, contest-math

> A1. $(150,9,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,6,33)$
>
> Let $$T_0=2,\quad T_1=3,\quad T_2=6,$$ and for $n\ge3$, $$T_n=(n+4)T_{n-1}-4nT_{n-2}+(4n-8)T_{n-3}.$$
>
> The first few terms are $$2,3,6,14,40,152,784,5168,40576,363392.$$
>
> Find, with proof, a formula for $T_n$ of the form $T_n=A_n+B_n$, where $(A_n)$ and $(B_n)$ are well-known sequences.

I found that:

$$T_n - n! = 2^n$$ and verified that $T_0 = 2^0 + 1 = 2$

Hence,

$$T_n = 2^n + n!$$

I need to prove that:

$$T_{n+1} = 2^{n+1} + (n+1)!$$

Which I can't do.

I went back and stated:

$$T_{n+1} = nT_{n} + T_n + 4T_n - 4nT_{n-1} - 4T_{n-1} + 4T_{n-2} + T_{n-2} - 8T_{n-2}$$

What to do next?

Comment: Since you have proved $T_{n}=2^n+n!$ for all natural $n$, then you just need to substitute $n-> n+1$ in $T_{n}=2^n+n!$ to get $T_{n+1}=2^{n+1}+(n+1)!$

Comment: The induction is not difficult if you found the solution already. I on the other hand is curious how you come up with the solution.

Comment: @ILUA, I have **NOT** proved that, that is the conjecture I am TRYING to prove using Induction.

Answer (score 8):

$T_n = 2^n + n!$ is true for $n=0,1,2$.  Let's assume it is also true for $n=k,k+1,k+2$ where,

- $T_{k} = 2^{k} + (k)!$
- $T_{k+1} = 2^{k+1} + (k+1)!$
- $T_{k+2} = 2^{k+2} + (k+2)!$.

Then, let's prove it for n=k+3.

Using  $ \; T_n = (n+4) T_{n-1} -4n T_{n-2} + (4n-8)T_{n-3}$, we get

$T_{k+3} = (k+7) \cdot 2^{k+2} + (k+7)(k+2)! - (k+3) \cdot 2^{k+3} - 4(k+3)(k+1)! + (k+1) \cdot 2^{k+2} + 4(k+1)! = \\ = 2^{k+2} (k+7 - 2k - 6 + k + 1) + (k^2 +9k+14 -4k -12 + 4) (k+1)! = \\ = 2^{k+2} \cdot 2 + (k^2 +5k+6)(k+1)! = 2^{k+3} + (k+3)!$

Case closed....

---

Irrelevant PS.
$T_{k+1} - T_k = 2^k + k \cdot k! = T_k + (k-1)k! \; \Rightarrow T_{k+1} = 2T_k + (k-1)k!$

---

Just came to mind:
Using $ \; T_n = (n+4) T_{n-1} -4n T_{n-2} + (4n-8)T_{n-3}$ we get
$$T_n - 2T_{n-1} = (n+2)(T_{n-1} - 2T_{n-2}) - (2n-4)(T_{n-2} - 2T_{n-3})$$
Let's assume $A_n = T_n - 2T_{n-1}$, we get
$$A_n = (n+2)A_{n-1} - (2n-4)A_{n-2} \; \; \; \; for \; \; n \ge 3.$$
$A_n = -1, 0, 2, 12, .....$

Comment: How can you change $n \to n-1$ ?

Comment: I didn't change anything, *confused* I just showed that if it is true for k,k+1, and k+2, then it is true for k+3 also....

Comment: I do not think the proof is valid. I did *NOT* yet prove that: $T_n = 2^n + n!$ hence I *cannot* change $n \to n-1$ for example.

Comment: It is a valid use of mathematical induction. It is true for n=0,1,2. Now, let's assume it is also true for n=k,k+1, and k+2. Now using the given formula ($T_n=(n+4)T_{n−1}−4nT_{n−2}+(4n−8)T_{n−3}$) prove it for n=k+3, and you will get, $T_{k+3} = 2^{k+3} + (k+3)!$.

Comment: @Tahir, That is the point. You **cant** assume it is true for $n = k+1$. the point is to prove that $P(k+1)$ is true using $P(k)$. You cannot assume it is already true for $k+1$!

Comment: O mon dio, Yes I can assume it. I can even assume it for n=k+1874636. Point is it is true for n=0,1,2, then I assume for n=k,k+1,k+2, and prove that it is also true for n=k+3. Therefore, it is true for n=4,5,6,7,8,9,10,.................

Comment: @TahirImanov, sorry but I have to agree with Amad27. Okay. Prove that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$ Assume it is true for $n=k$ then assume: 

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$ is true. You dont assume $P(n+1)$ is true because that is what you are trying to show; I would say you need to reread on induction. (-1)

Comment: Lebes and Amad, I suggest you to study induction first. You are just making Argumentum ad ignorantiam.

Comment: Lebes: Perhaps I can clear up some confusion. What you have probably been taught as induction is something called "weak induction", where you prove $T(n+1)$ from $T(n)$ and a base case $T(0)$, which is indeed not what Tahir is doing. What Tahir is using is something called "strong induction" (see Wikipedia), where you prove $T(n+1)$ from all previous truths - in this case he is only using $T(n), T(n-1)$ and $T(n-2)$, and for this to hold one needs three base cases, for example $T(0), T(1), T(2)$.

Comment: @TahirImanov, apologies, (+1). I was automatically assuming that you meant WEAK induction, which is what I pointed out. Sorry again, (+1) deserved =).

Comment: @TahirImanov +1 simply for the "O mon dio" comment (and because it was a nice answer of course).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested in what the definitive Putnam problems/solutions book has to say:

---

*Answer.* We have $T_n=n!+2^n$.

*Motivation.* The hardest part of this problem is guessing the formula. There are not many "well-known sequences" to guess. Observe that the terms are becoming divisible by high powers of $2$ (but not any other prime), and the ratio of the last two terms given is roughly $8$, and the ratio of the previous two is roughly $7$.

**Solution.** The formula $T_n=n!+2^n$ can be verified by induction.

Alternatively, set $t_n=n!+2^n$. Clearly $t_0=2=T_0, t_1=3=T_1$ and $t_2=6=T_2$. Also
$$
t_n-nt_{n-1}=2^n-n2^{n-1}.
$$
Now $2^n$ and $n2^{n-1}$ are both solutions of the linear recursion
$$
f_n-4f_{n-1}+4f_{n-2}=0;\tag{1}
$$
this follows from direct substitution. Since $t_n-nt_{n-1}$ is a linear combination of solutions to $(1)$, it must also be a solution. Hence
$$
(t_n-nt_{n-1})-4(t_{n-1}-(n-1)t_{n-2})+4(t_{n-2}-(n-2)t_{n-3})=0,
$$
or equivalently,
$$
t_n = (n+4)t_{n-1}-4nt_{n-2}+(4n-8)t_{n-3}.
$$
Thus $t_n=T_n$, because they are identical for $n=0,1,2$ and satisfy the same third-order recursion $(1)$ for $n\geq 3$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 2):

Let's prove it by induction. At first we should establish the base case. $P(n_0) = T_0 = 0! + 2^0 = 1 + 1 = 2$ which is true. One can check the same with $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Now let's establish the strong induction hyphotesis which is as follows. $\forall n \ge 3$ and $ n \in \mathbb{Z} $ we have that $P(n ) = T_k = k! + 2^k $ for $ 1 \ge k \ge n. $

We shall prove that $T_{n+1} = (n+1) + 2^{n+1} $. To do so we're gonna perform the following algebra.
Using our strong hyphotesis and the given formula for $T_n$ set:
\begin{equation}
 T_{n+1} = [(n+1)+4)(n! + 2^n)] -(4(n+1))[(n-1)! + 2^{n-1}] + (4(n-1))[(n-2)! + 2^{n-2}] 
\end{equation}
After being multiplied out, the terms look like:
$$ T_{n+1} = 2^n + (n+1)! + 2^{n+2} + 2^n\cdot n + 4n! -4n! -4(n-1)! -2^{n+1}\cdot n - 2^{n+1} + 4(n-1)! + 2^n\cdot n - 2^n $$
As you can see, many terms will cancel out and in fact all the terms will (check by yourself), except by the following, giving us:
\begin{align*}
 T_{n+1} &= (n+1)! + 2^{n+2} - 2^{n+1} \\ &= (n+1)! + 2^n(2^2 - 2) \\ &= (n+1)! + 2^n(4-2) \\ &= (n+1)! + 2^n(2) \\ &= (n+1)! + 2^{n+1} \blacksquare 
\end{align*}
Quite elegantly done. QED.